# Kendo UI Mobile ListView - Load more button doesn't work

Tags: kendo-ui

Looks like the "Press to load more" option does not work on the latest version of Kendo Mobile UI (2012-q3). I tried it on a Galaxy Nexus and an iPod.

http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/listview/press-to-load-more.html

Any ideas for a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug, we fixed it and the fix will be available in the next internal build.

As a workaround, you can re-set the event handling on the button (init code taken from the demo):

```
    var listview = $("#load-more").kendoMobileListView({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        template: $("#load-more-template").text(),
        loadMore: true
    }).data("kendoMobileListView");

    listview._loadButton
        .off("click.kendoMobileListView")
        .on("touchend.kendoMobileListView click.kendoMobileListView", $.proxy(listview._nextPage, listview));
```

This will break the **stopLoadMore** method, so better get the update when its available.